# strip string from url in Python

Tags: python

input: url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/number/`

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/` is consistent for each page number.

output: `number`

Instead of slicing the url `url[-4:-1]`, Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Split at `/`, find index of "data" and take everything from that index on, if you want to allow for multiple things after it. But why do you want to avoid slicing? I think you're going to end up doing it at some phase anyway, I don't see how you can cut anything out from a larger thing without slicing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) and [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

```
import urlparse
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/number/"
path = urlparse.urlparse(url).path
val = path.split("/")[2]
print val
```

This prints:

```
number
```

---

The output of `urlparse` for the above URL is

```
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='127.0.0.1:8000', path='/data/number/', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

We are utilizing the `path` portion of this tuple. We split it on `/` and take the second index.

Answer (score 2):

use urlparse module life would be easier

```
from urlparse import urlparse
urlparse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/number/').path.split('/')[2]
```